# Someone always downvotes my question without helping me to understand what I did wrong

Tags: support, down-votes, new-users

Whenever I post a question (usually on Stack Overflow), I almost always get a downvote within the first few minutes of it being posted. I try my best to follow all the rules, search before posting, and correct formatting of the post, but when I ask for help, now I am greeted with the "Careful what you post, you might be banned" message because 2 or 3 of my questions have 1 downvote on them.

I think users should be required to provide a reason, or at the very least a comment describing why that they think the content shouldn't be on Stack Overflow and/or isn't useful. This would help encourage new users like me to contribute content that could help, rather than hold back in fear of getting post banned.

Comment: MSO is more suitable for this question if the downvotes have been received on SO.

Comment: I doubt you have a cross network stalker doing it. More likely you still have things to improve in your questions, and the most attention is received then posting the question, for good or for bad. I know it's frustrating, but that's the way Stack Overflow is working.

Comment: "someone"? there are [thousands of them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601)

Answer (score 6):

The downvote states that the answer is not useful, and/or not well formatted, and/or not well researched.

Let's just take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353330/mapsapi-v3-removing-all-points-of-a-polygon-overlay) as example.

**What you did (before the edit):**

You are stating that you are having trouble with your app. But in my opinion you did not describe **what exactly** your problem was.

If I didn't take a look at your sample, I would not have understood your question.

**What you should do instead:**

1. Include the minimum of images to show what exactly your problem is, if it is graphically representable.
2. Include the quintessence of code necessary to understand where you suspect the problem.